# How to run a Docker image from the ECS repo?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have managed to push a Docker image to the ECS repo (I also pushed it to docker hubs repo).

I have created a cluster and an EC2 instance with public IP.

What now? How do you run the server? Do you have to push it from the repo somewhere? Will it just run automatically now? Do I have to setup a script somewhere?

Comment: Have you followed https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/ to create your cluster? If so, what is the problem you have encountered?

Comment: I followed it. It’s a bit outdated. After following it I can’t find the load balancing IP address. I add the task, cluster, service and I’m not sure what to do next.

Comment: @grabury Have you created a service with desired number of tasks? or Have you tried running single task?

Answer (score 0):

You specify the repo to pull your container from as part of the container setup step *inside the task definition*.

[image: button]

From here, you'll see a prompt for you to specify where the container should be pulled from:

[image]

Once that's all complete, you need to make sure your EC2 instance is part of your cluster (which you also should create). As part of your cluster configuration, you can launch your task on a host that belongs to that cluster (or setup a service to manage the launching for you). When a task is launched on a host, all of the containers specified in that task get pulled and started via whatever [entrypoint script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) you've defined in your dockerfile (or, alternatively, in your task definition).